# Probability in getting two numbers exactly the same after rolling three dices?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of getting two numbers the same having three dices? I had this on my exam, it sounded super easy but isn't so.

**Solution:**
I know that there are $$6^3$$ combinations for all three dices. Then I just wrote  the following:

[image]

And the combinations that I want are: $$first-second:(1,1,x),(2,2,x),(3,3,x),(4,4,x),(5,5,x),(6,6,x)$$

$$second-third:(x,1,1),(x,2,2),(x,3,3),(x,4,4),(x,5,5),(x,6,6)$$
$$first-third:(1,x,1),(2,x,2),(3,x,3),(4,x,4),(5,x,5),(6,x,6)$$
wich gives me the combination of $6+6+6=18$ and final result $18/216$, which is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly two the same, or at least two the same?

Comment: Exactly the same

Comment: Refer to Lovsovs' answer-hint.  What you've done so far doesn't exclude, for example, (1,1,1).

Comment: Still unclear. Do you mean exactly **2** the same?

Comment: Yes exactly to the same...

Comment: @drhab, how else would you interpret it?

Comment: @tilper exactly the same can be interpreted as: not almost the same. Essential in your comment is the word *two*.

Comment: @drhab, I don't understand, what does "not almost the same" mean in this context?

Comment: I' m sorry for confusing you, but I don't know how to explain in furhter, so three dices are thrown and I want let ' say number 2 on the first dice, number 2 on the second and on the third everything but not number two, and I'm trying to find the combination for all of the numbers in that way..

Comment: @tilper Don't bother about it. Things are clear now. The answer on your comment should have been "exactly two the same". That has not the same meaning as "exactly the same".

Comment: Can anyone give an explanation solution to this problem...

Comment: @drhab, OK.  In general they're certainly different but I think it's clear from the context what OP meant by "exactly the same."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For each of your eighteen cases, what can $x$ be?

Comment: depends, for (1,1x) x can be [2-6] but still confused..., and that 5/6 but what do I do with it now?

Comment: @wesewx The point is that for each of the cases you listed, $x$ can be $5$ different things. Can you see the solution now?

Comment: Yes and no, The problem is I' m not sure how to embed into my initial solution...

Comment: @wesewx For each of the eighteen cases, you have $5$ different possibilities for $x$. That gives $18\times 5$ possibilities in all.

Comment: @wesewx No worries!

Comment: @wesewx And your reputation has grown uptil now with $15$. Hold on!!

Comment: @drhab you mean +17, answer accpeted-->+2 xd

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

$$\Pr(\text{exactly }2\text{ the same})=1-\Pr(3\text{ distinct})-\Pr(3\text{ the same})=1-\frac56\frac46-\frac16\frac16$$